# Deleted Ubuntu, then Windows 7 , now Windows is not booting from cd

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed a dual operating system (Ubuntu 9 and Windows 7). Unknowingly I deleted Ubuntu partition. Then there comes the grub rescue error. 
After that I again installed Ubuntu from live cd and during installation erased the Windows 7 partition from my hard disk.

Now I am trying to install Windows 7 but it doesn't boot.

This time I have only Ubuntu installed on my laptop. I want to remove all this Ubuntu etc and I want to install Windows 7 only.

Answer (score 1):

Fist of all make sure all you data is save.
Next check if BIOS boots from Disk (you need to hit a key during boot)

during the Win 7 install select advanced options and delete the disk (this WILL DELETE ALL you DATA!!!) and select to install Win 7 on this empty partition (win will create a small boot partition it self)

Answer (score 0):

Try to boot from pendrive after making it bootable for windows 7 from another windows based os system and then boot. Make sure you have configured BIOS to boot from Pendrive.